# I'm getting trouble with subprocess.Popen and split command in python

Tags: python, bash, bots, telethon

Actually I want to edit my python script ( for running tg bot ) such that when i trigger command it actually has some pre defined command before that. Like instead of typing whole command, */run bash test.sh url* it should work for */run url*. In short, I want that *bash test.sh* to be already defined in my script. Take a look to original script.

```
def shell(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
message = update.effective_message
cmd = message.text.split(' ', 1)
if len(cmd) == 1:
    message.reply_text('No command to execute was given.')
    return
cmd = cmd[1]
process = subprocess.Popen(
    cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
reply = ''
stderr = stderr.decode()
stdout = stdout.decode()
if stdout:
    reply += f"*Stdout*\n`{stdout}`\n"
    LOGGER.info(f"Shell - {cmd} - {stdout}")
if stderr:
    reply += f"*Stderr*\n`{stderr}`\n"
    LOGGER.error(f"Shell - {cmd} - {stderr}")
if len(reply) > 3000:
```

Now I wanted my bot to predefine some part of my subprocess command. Like I want to keep *bash test.sh* as predefined so that i have to not write whole command again and again. I tried myself.

```
def shell(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
message = update.effective_message
cmd = message.text.split(' ', 1)
if len(cmd) == 1:
    message.reply_text('No command to execute was given.')
    return
cmd = cmd[1]
process = subprocess.Popen(
    bash, test.sh, cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
stdout, stderr = process.communicate()
reply = ''
stderr = stderr.decode()
stdout = stdout.decode()
if stdout:
    reply += f"*Stdout*\n`{stdout}`\n"
    LOGGER.info(f"Shell - bash test.sh {cmd} - {stdout}")
if stderr:
    reply += f"*Stderr*\n`{stderr}`\n"
    LOGGER.error(f"Shell - bash test.sh {cmd} - {stderr}")
if len(reply) > 3000:
```

But this don't work for me, so please help me to get correct syntax.

Comment: if you use `shell=True` then you should create string `"bash test.sh " +  cmd`. If you use without `shell=True` then you should create list `["bash", "test.sh", cmd]`

Comment: Can you check if Logger.info and Logger.error need changes.

Comment: Logger doesn't need any changes.

Comment: I need to use command **/shell bash test.sh  -H GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN  -r repo username**

Comment: as I said in answer - you have to use single string `"bash test.sh -H GITHUB_OAUTH_TOKEN -r repo username"`

Comment: Actually my phone got ded and was not able to write/edit the statement.

Comment: Here repo and username are the variable, and also in script there should be space between repo and username. I can't crack how to give space between two adjacent variable.

Comment: Letme try with shell=False

Comment: frankly, I don't understand where is the problem - this should know everyone. You have strings so you can use different functions to format it - `"text " + variable + " text"` or `"text {} text".format(variable)`, or `f-string` like `f"text {variable} text"`

Comment: and if you have list `["text", variable, "text"]` then `" ".join(list)`

Comment: I add all examples in answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `shell=True` then you should use single string

```
 subprocess.Popen("bash test.sh " +  cmd, ..., shell=True)
```

If you use without `shell=True` then you should use list

```
 subprocess.Popen(["bash", "test.sh", cmd], ..., shell=False)
```

---

**EDIT:**

```
script = 'test.sh'
token = 'AD........45'
repo = 'python-examples'
user = 'furas'

cmd = "bash {} -H {} -r {} {}".format(script, token, repo, user)
print(cmd)

cmd = f"bash {script} -H {token} -r {repo} {user}"
print(cmd)

data = ["bash", script, "-H", token, "-r", repo, user]
cmd = " ".join(data)
print(cmd)
```

Results:

```
bash test.sh -H AD........45 -r python-examples furas
bash test.sh -H AD........45 -r python-examples furas
bash test.sh -H AD........45 -r python-examples furas
```